# Writing a procedure that's callable to C code for void?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

**Write an assembly procedure called increment that is callable from C. The procedure should take a pointer to 32-bit integer as a parameter, and should increment the integer to which the parameter points. The C prototype for the function is as follows:**

`void increment (int *p);`

**provide only the assembly code from the procedure label to the ret instruction.**

So, the question has to be done in Assembly x86-64 (in this case, E registers since it's asking for 32-bit). It's generally a short segment of logical instructions of 3-12 lines of code in **_start:** that I have to code assuming everything else is already declared and defined. For example:

```
mov rax,[x]

mov rbx,[y]

cqo

idiv rbx

mov [q],rax

mov [r],rdx
```

My issue is it's asking for the procedure to take a pointer to a 32-bit integer as a parameter AND incrementing the integer to where the parameter is pointing.

I'm not sure how I would go about in translating this C code into NASM, or a callable function:

```
void increment  (int *p) {
    *p = *p + 1;
}
```

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with? Can you access the argument? Can you dereference a pointer? Can you do addition? Note that the size of the pointer does not depend on what it points to so it's still 64 bit.

Comment: `void increment (int p);` takes a value, not a pointer.  But apparently you had `void increment (int* *p)` but didn't use code-formatting to protect the asterisks from being markdown.  So that's too many levels of indirection, a pointer to a pointer.  If that was actually part of the assignment, it's buggy and doesn't match the text which tells you to take a pointer to an integer.  Anyway, use a C compiler to have it make an example for you.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, I am so sorry about that. I tried to italicize but it seems like the asterisk was put there. I fixed it. Again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try something like `increment: inc dword [rdi]; ret`

Comment: Hey @fuz sorry for the late response, didn't get the notification. Would that be the first part of the line within the _start: section? Since it's a 32-bit wouldn't you be using an edi register, instead of rdi?

Comment: @Atlas This would be the implementation of the `increment` function.  In 64 bit mode, pointers are 64 bit long, regardless of what data type they point to.  Hence `dword` (for the size of the datum you want to increment) but `[rdi]`.

Comment: @fuz sorry in advance for the dumb questions, as this is my first time ever coding in Assembly, but I assume there are more than just one line of code after incrementing such as scanf, printf, .L1? Or is that basically it?

Comment: @Atlas The function you want to translate does not have a call to `printf` or `scanf`.  I do not understand why you have calls to these functions in the first place.

Comment: @fuz Would I be able to show you through visual representation either through screen share really quick? If not I'll try my best to explain it here; I have a C file in replit that the .asm file has to call to, and I know from textbook scanf is an important detail for C language. If you say it's not important in this aspect, then that line of code is basically all I would need in order to follow the question on hand?

Comment: @Atlas The question seems to ask you to call into the ASM code from C, not the other way round.  I don't see anything about `scanf` and `printf` in it.  Perhaps there are some unstated assumptions in it.  But if the question is just to translate that one function, the code I gave is sufficient.

Comment: @fuz Gotcha. Just to double-check, the bolded question is what you're referring to correct?

Comment: @Atlas Yes, correct.

Comment: @fuz Oh and I just noticed, why the semicolon after [rdi] ? Isn't semicolons used to make comments?

Comment: @Atlas I used that to separate the two instructions.  You might need to place the instructions on separate lines instead.

Comment: Figures just wanted to make sure it wasn't a comment on purpose.

Comment: @fuz Out of the blue, but...doesn't `increment: inc dword [rdi]; ret` have no way of callable to C function?

Comment: Well you have to export the symbol of course, but then it is perfectly callable.

Comment: @fuz So it would still be callable without? If not, which code would I use to export the symbol?

Comment: It is callable without being exported, just not visible.  To make it visible, write `global increment`